# Double Integral with a Delta Function

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta, multiple-integral

Consider the integral $$\int_0^b\int_0^a\delta(x-y)f(x,y)dxdy$$ where $b>a$. I know that we need to integrate over the larger range first (i.e do the $y$ integral) and then do the remaining integral (i.e the $x$ integral). However I'm having trouble properly understanding why? An image is attached below - it seems to me that whether you integrate over x or y first you still capture all of the relevant part of the line y=x...[image] Would anybody be able to provide a nice worded explanation or ideally something involving a diagram showing the region of integration? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^a \delta(x-y)f(x,y)dx = 1_{[0;a]}(y) f(y,y)$$ ie $f(y,y)$ if $y\in [0;a]$ and $0$ elsewhere

So $$\int_0^b \left(\int_0^a \delta(x-y)f(x,y)dx \right)dy  =\int_0^b  1_{[0;a]}(y)f(y,y) dy  =\int_0^a f(y,y)dy $$

Comment: You have mixed the variables up here (final integral should be in x?), but I get the point - however I'm looking for a more detailed explanation of why your middle line implies the order of integration - maybe this might be obvious by explaining it in terms of the integration region (I know what the reason is, and sort of why it makes sense but not completely so this reply hasn't really gone far enough)?

Comment: @Watw I didn't mix variables, just skipped a step. I didn't change the order of integration but note that you can do it (if you find that easier) because of the Fubini Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini.27s_theorem_for_integrable_functions)

Comment: Oh I seeeeeeeeeee, I got it thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

As a slightly more general case, let us evaluate the integral for the region $g_1(x)<y<g_2(x)$ and $x_1<x<x_2$. Thus our integral takes the form
\begin{equation}
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathrm{d}x\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)}\mathrm{d}y\delta(x-y)f(x,y)
\end{equation}
Note that in this case, the limit of integration can't be changed. This can be simplified in the following manner using the Heavyside function $\Theta(x)$ as follows
$$\int_\alpha^\beta f(x)\delta(x-a)\mathrm{d}x=f(a)\Theta(a-\alpha)\Theta(\beta-a)$$
Mathematically, the $\Theta$ functions take care of the fact that the integral is non-zero only when $\alpha<a<\beta$. This can be used for the integral given above to get
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathrm{d}xf(x,x)\Theta(x-g_1(x))\Theta(g_2(x)-x)$$
Now let us consider a special case $g_1(x)=y_1\in\mathbb{R}$, $g_2(x)=y_2\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e., constant $y$ limits. Thus we get
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\mathrm{d}xf(x,x)\Theta(x-y_1)\Theta(y_2-x)=\int_{\max\{x_1,y_1\}}^{\min\{x_2,y_2\}}\mathrm{d}xf(x,x)$$
Finally, if we consider the case given above, then this gives
$$\int_{0}^{a}\mathrm{d}xf(x,x)$$
which is the same as obtained above.